# Is it a bad practice to put JUnit test method into the tested class?

Tags: java, junit

Consider a Java class with small library-style static methods.

Is it a bad practice to place JUnit test methods in the same class?

I see the following pros:

- JUnit test as a self-documentation is right near the method code
- Will be easy to move this code to another class or package

What are the contras, and why it is a general practice to always separate the test code?

An example:

```
import org.junit.*;

public class HtmlUtils {
    public static String normalizeBrs(String html) {
        return html.replaceAll("<br\\s*/?>", "<br/>");
    }

    @Test
    public void testNormalizeBrs() {
        Assert.assertEquals(normalizeBrs("hello <br /> world <br>"), "hello <br/> world <br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: u don't need the test to run the production code, so why should be in the same class?

Comment: Sometimes this might have value.  I agree with the other answers, if you are talking about unit tests against code that is getting shipped to a customer somewhere else. But for testing continuous delivery, on in-house code, where you need to cut down the cycle time of moving from one environment to the next, you might be onto something here.  Your approach removes a critical point of failure from the assembly, which is the independently maintained and deployed junit test stack.  Also simplifies ops side of CI. Cool idea would love to hear more about it.

Answer (score 4):

( Is it a bad practice to put JUnit test method into the tested class? )

**Absolutely**.

The key reason here: **[single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**. A class, a method, any *thing* in programming should support/provide exactly **one** responsibility.

The core responsibility of your production code is to fulfill its "production purpose".

In other words: business logic is business logic. Nothing *else*.

Anything that doesn't belong in that bucket ... goes **somewhere *else***.

Testing is such a "thing", aspect, responsibility, however you name it.

The more typical approach is to even have **different** projects for production and test code.

When your production class is x.y.Z ... then the test class would be x.y.ZTest; but although they reside in the same package, you would normally place them into different source location folders.

And beyond that: **refactoring** for Java is can be seen as "solved problem" in 2017. Moving around methods into different classes, or changing package names is so easy today that you (absolutely) do not need to worry about that. (if refactoring looks so dangerous to you, that you consider polluting your production code with test code, then well: learn how to use modern day tools)

Also, if you put your test methods inside of the tested class, you will probably end up testing the internal implementation. This is not what you are supposed to test. You should test against the class API; your tests should be independent of the internal implementation.

Answer (score 2):

you may not notice any difference if your package is small.

But imagine you have a package containing 1000s of classes then having 10s of thousands of methods. meaning 10s of thousands of tests.

so what will happen if having all codes + tests together?

for something like that you may end up loading memory with garbage that will never actually serve any purpose.

This is why general practice always encourages you to have them separated. by following this for smaller package you are actually training yourself for bigger projects too.

Answer (score 1):

We keep source code separate from the test code.

Here are the reasons I know.

1. We create build of source code for production and it shouldn't contain test code. Unnecessary increase in code size.
2. Separate test project helps. So that we can run test build after regular intervals against source to check if everything is in check. e.g. General practice is , when you do code changes and push the code, these test builds are triggered and then your new changes are checked against it.
3. Test cases are for internal use only to make sure we maintain quality of code. Most of the customers not interested in it.

Feel free to add more in this list.

Cheers!!!

Comment: 4. Not exposing additional methods in API.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of *nafas*

**Keep tests in the same location as the source code**

If the test source is kept in the same location as the tested classes, both test and class will compile during a build. This forces you to keep the tests and classes synchronized during development. Indeed, unit tests not considered part of the normal build quickly become dated and useless.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076265/testing-debugging/junit-best-practices.html
http://www.kyleblaney.com/junit-best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

If you have your tests within the production code, then:

1. you'll have additional dependencies (and therefore bigger size of jar/war/ear file, more time to load, more memory ressources needed) for your production code (e.g. Mockito, ...) which is absolutely unnecessary for the application to run
2. you'll have additional attributes within your class, needing for memory ressources and maybe are in conflict with the attributes of your application attributes
3. the test methods have to be public, so the test methods are part of the api of your production code (which is totally confusing for people wanting to use your application code)
4. the classes are becoming longer and harder to maintain
5. you're hurting the conventions e.g. of maven

Answer (score 0):

One tried and tested model is that used by the standard Maven project layout, and by many other build frameworks.

We have separate `src/main` and `src/test` directories, but they are both in the same project.

`src/main` contains all the production code, and nothing else.

`src/test` contains unit tests.

The build configuration specifies dependencies, and knows the difference between test classes and production classes.

Some dependencies are required for testing. Most fundamentally, jUnit itself. Also thinks like mocking libraries (JMock, Mockito), utilities like Hamcrest, tools like WireMock or RestClientDriver, test libraries of your own, etc.

You don't need these libraries for your production code to run, so you shouldn't bundle them in the build, nor have the build declare them as dependencies.

In a test-driven project, you would typically expect to have many more lines of test code than of production code. So including test code will seriously increase the size of your distribution.

Maven puts the test dependencies in the classpath when compiling and running tests, but does *not* put them on the classpath when compiling production code. That means that if you try to use jUnit, Mockito, etc. in a production class, you'll get a compilation error -- which is what you want.

So:

- production code and its corresponding test are in separate directories, within the same project
- building the distribution includes compiling and running the tests
- the built artifact is no bigger than necessary, since it does not include test code

All of this also has the advantage that Java programmers tend to be familiar with this layout. Programmers like to not be surprised.

Your observations:

- "JUnit test as a self-documentation is right near the method code"

This is a valid observation, and there is some precedent for writing
tests inline for this reason. However it tends to have been in environments where the size of the distributed code didn't matter, or where there was a means to strip out or ignore the test code as part of the build. For example, in C, the tests might be in a `#IFDEF TEST` preprocessor directive. This holds the risk that when you remove the "test" code, you remove something that was actually required for the software to work -- i.e. code that only works when the test code is present!

Because the Maven layout is so familiar to Java programmers, they know where to
find unit tests. Many IDEs (or plugins) allow you to toggle between a class and its unit test with a keystroke -- as long as you follow naming conventions.

- "Will be easy to move this code to another class or package"

In practice this is seldom a problem, but some IDEs (or plugins) automate it anyway. For example, I believe that in IntelliJ IDEA, if you rename a class, or move it to another package, its corresponding test class also gets renamed or moved -- again, as long as you follow naming conventions.

--

My recommendation is that you adopt these well-established practices, whether using Maven, Gradle or some other build system.